# Non-deterministic functions in stream processing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-storm, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams

Some systems like StreamScope require functions to be deterministic (as well as the order they are processed) this is due to the fact that each message has its sequence number when in a stream. In case of failures, this sequence number is used to determine whether an event should be recomputed or not (because it was persists by the stream), and so that downstream nodes do not compute the same events twice.

Does Flink, Spark Streaming, Kafka-Streams and Storm also require functions to be deterministic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. It depends ;)

The frameworks do no force you to provide deterministic functions.

In case of a failure some parts of your input data will be recomputed. Intermediate result will be discarded. Thus, the newly generated intermediate result might be different to the previous one (before the failure) if you use non-deterministic functions. However, if you don't care about this, it's fine to use non-determinism.

Furthermore, it depend on the semantics you are using.

Flink/Storm(Trident)/Spark (exactly-once processing):

- Flink offeres exaclty-once only for certain sources and sinks
- for this, some output will be deleted and recomputed in case of failure

  - Flink for example can truncating a file. Thus, you might want to make sure to not consumer output that might get reversed later on (or you might not care...)
- Spark/Storm micro-batching automatically prevents downstream consumer to read non-committed output automatically (I think for some sinks, Flink does the same)

Flink/Storm/Kafka-Streams (at-least-once processing):

- if you run with at-least-once processing semantics in case of failure, you will get some duplicates in you output. Thus, if you use non-deterministic functions, those "duplicates" might actually have different values (due to non-determinism)